# why this code has this error : error: "conflicting types for ‘create_roulette_numbers’" in lines 15 and 79

Tags: c, compiler-errors, function-definition, function-call

```
// BINGO Game 

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#define SPN 7
#define BTT 99 

int create_random_number(int released_numbers[SPN*SPN], int released_numbers_count);
void create_card_game(int matriz[SPN][SPN]);
void print_card_game(int matriz[SPN][SPN]);
void create_roulette_numbers(int lista[BTT]);
bool iguality_hunter_matriz(int released_numbers[SPN*SPN], int released_numbers_count, int random_number);
int create_roulette_numbers(int roulette_released_numbers[BTT], int roulette_released_numbers_count);
void create_roulette(int lista[BTT]);
bool iguality_hunter_list(int roulette_released_numbers[BTT], int roulette_released_numbers_count, int roulette_numbers);

int create_random_number(int released_numbers[SPN*SPN], int released_numbers_count)
{
    int random_number;
    do
    {
        random_number=rand()%100;
    }
    while(iguality_hunter_matriz(released_numbers, released_numbers_count, random_number));
    
    return random_number;
}



void create_card_game(int matriz[SPN][SPN])
{
    int released_numbers[SPN*SPN];
    int released_numbers_count = 0;
    int random_number;
    for(int i=0; i<SPN; i++)
        for(int j=0; j<SPN; j++)
        {
            random_number = create_random_number(released_numbers, released_numbers_count);
            matriz[i][j] = random_number;
            released_numbers[released_numbers_count] = random_number;
            released_numbers_count++;
        }
}



bool iguality_hunter_matriz(int released_numbers[SPN*SPN], int released_numbers_count, int random_number)
{
    for(int i=0; i<released_numbers_count; i++)
    {
        if (released_numbers[i] == random_number)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}



void print_card_game(int matriz[SPN][SPN])
{
    printf("\n");
    for(int i=0; i<SPN; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<SPN; j++)
        {
            printf("|");
            printf(" %2d ", matriz[i][j]);
        }
        printf("|\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}



int create_roulette_numbers(int roulette_released_numbers[BTT], int roulette_released_numbers_count)
{
    int roulette_numbers;
    do
    {
        roulette_numbers=rand()%100;
    }
    while(iguality_hunter_list(roulette_released_numbers, roulette_released_numbers_count, roulette_numbers));
    
    return roulette_numbers;
}



bool iguality_hunter_list(int roulette_released_numbers[BTT], int roulette_released_numbers_count, int roulette_numbers)
{
    for(int i=0; i<roulette_released_numbers_count; i++)
    {
        if (roulette_released_numbers[i] == roulette_numbers)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}



void create_roulette(int lista[BTT])
{
    int roulette_released_numbers[BTT];
    int roulette_released_numbers_count = 0;
    int roulette_numbers;
    for(int i=0; i<BTT; i++)
    {
        roulette_numbers = create_roulette_numbers(roulette_released_numbers, roulette_released_numbers_count);
        lista[i] = roulette_numbers;
        roulette_released_numbers[roulette_released_numbers_count] = roulette_numbers;
        roulette_released_numbers_count++;
    }
}



void print_roulette_number()
{
    int n;
    n=create_roulette_numbers(int roulette_released_numbers[BTT], int roulette_released_numbers_count);
    printf("e o numero da roleta e: %d", n);
}



int main()
{
    int card_game[SPN][SPN];
    int roulette[BTT];
    
    srand(time(NULL));
    
    create_card_game(card_game);
    print_card_game(card_game);
    

    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to create a bingo game where the game card has 49 random numbers but that are not repeated with each other, until then all right the problem started when I try to do the same for the number that comes out in roulette, this will also be random and not repeat, for this I adapted the functions i had created for the offspring of the game card,  but in this case ended up giving this problem : "conflicting types for ‘create_roulette_numbers’"  in lines 15 and 79. also give this problem:

```
error: too few arguments to function ‘create_roulette_numbers’
  124 |     n=create_roulette_numbers(int roulette_released_numbers[BTT], int roulette_released_numbers_count);
```

```
error: too few arguments to function ‘create_roulette_numbers’
  124 |     n=create_roulette_numbers(int roulette_released_numbers[BTT], int roulette_released_numbers_count);
```

i realy dont know how to repair that.

Comment: The code has two, different, prototypes for `create_roulette_numbers`. The first one `void create_roulette_numbers(int lista[BTT]);` does not match the definition.

Answer (score 0):

This record

```
n=create_roulette_numbers(int roulette_released_numbers[BTT], int roulette_released_numbers_count);
```

is invalid. Instead of supplying argument expressions you placed declarations within the function call.

In any case the function definition

```
void print_roulette_number()
{
    int n;
    n=create_roulette_numbers(int roulette_released_numbers[BTT], int roulette_released_numbers_count);
    printf("e o numero da roleta e: %d", n);
}
```

does not make sense because the function does not have entities to pass them as expressions to the call of the function `create_roulette_numbers`.

Apart from this the function is declared twice with different numbers of parameters and return types

```
void create_roulette_numbers(int lista[BTT]);
```

and

```
int create_roulette_numbers(int roulette_released_numbers[BTT], int roulette_released_numbers_count);
```

In C you may not overload functions.